# Where should the service configuration go in meteor? At the client side or at the server side?

Tags: javascript, meteor, linkedin-api, meteor-accounts

I'm working on a custom login-with-linkedin button. I have `accounts-base`, `accounts-oauth`, and `pauli:accounts-linkedin` packages. I have used the client id and the secret from the linkedin developers site as follows

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update({
        'service': 'linkedin',
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'clientId': 'myClientId',
            'secret': 'mySecret'
        }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    });
});
```

In the iron router, I've also defined the waitOn function on /login template as follows:

```
this.route('login', {
    path: '/login',
    waitOn: function() {
       Accounts.loginServicesConfigured();
    }
});
```

Now, when I click on the button, a pop-up window opens but it doesn't load the linkedin login page and it says 'ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED'.
[image]

I have written the ServiceConfiguration in the Meteor.startup function at the client side. Am I right to write serviceconfiguration at the client side? or should I be writing it at the server side?

Answer (score 2):

It should be on the server-side. From the Meteor documentation here,

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice which says

> Login service configuration is sent from the server to the client over
>   DDP when your app starts up

I have done service configuration successfully for accounts-google on server side as well.

Comment: Okay. I've configured it on the server side, but still the 'client_id' in the url is undefined.

Comment: For me I didn't wrap it under `Meteor.startup`. Try to put it out of `Meteor.startup` and see if it works.

Comment: I've defined a settings.json in the root. I've removed whatever I've written from Meteor.startup function and put it in a separate file, called it configure-services.js which has this code: const services = Meteor.settings.private.oAuth;

const configure = function() {
 if(services) {
  for(let service in services) {
   ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert({service:service}, {
    $set: services[service]
   });
  }
 }
}
Meteor.server.configureServices = configure;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a generic solution for this [common issue](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html)

> First, add the service configuration package:
>
> meteor add service-configuration
>
> Then, in your app:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
      { service: 'weibo' },
      {
        $set: {
          clientId: '1292962797',
          loginStyle: 'popup',
          secret: '75a730b58f5691de5522789070c319bc'
        }
      }
    );
```

I usually just put a service-config.js file with this code in the server.